# How to keep track of library addresses on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to keep track of the address of the library that get loaded in my iOS program.
For example, how do i know the base address of the "facebook sdk" that get loaded in my iOS app? if i have an address, how do i map this address back to the "facebook sdk" ?

Thank you

Comment: what kind of address are you asking about? memory address or file system address? also what do you mean by "map this address back" ?

Comment: let me clarify, i want to find out all the dynamic library get loaded in the app, and its base address, how should i know that?

Comment: such as facebook SDK that I loaded